# javascript timer event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using setInterval function at the beginning of my program, but my problem is I don't want to wait when I start code. I want it to start immediately, after it will apply this timeinterval. Here is my code:

```
    function initialize() {
setInterval(function(){myFunc()},5000);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function initialize() {
    myFunc();
    setInterval(function(){myFunc()},5000);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Answer (score 5):

Call `myfunc()` just after the DOM is loaded

```
function initialize() {
    myFunc();//it will run without waiting for 5 seconds
    setInterval(myFunc,5000);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Comment: while the page loads - e.g. not onload but when the statement is reached by the interpreter

Comment: I tried your way but it doesn't display anything. I think I should call myFunc() onload.

Comment: i didn't know that your initialize function is ran on DomContentLoaded

Answer (score -2):

you can create a self invoking function as so:

```
(function(){
    myFunc();
    setInterval(function(){myFunc();},5000)
})();
function myFunc(){
    alert('works?');
}
```

this function will run as soon as the browser reads it, with no need to run it (like Ankit suggested).

Comment: That would STILL wait 5 seconds.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't display anything. Actually I tired what Ankit wrote. myFunc() doesn't display anything. It should work onLoad.

Comment: sure it wont work if you dont define a function named `myFunc()`, i updated the code, try it.